# Is it possible to generate a public default constructor as well as static factory method for an Immutables builder?

Tags: constructor, annotations, builder, immutables-library, static-factory

I'm trying to define a builder for an [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) value that has both a public default constructor and a static factory method, i.e.

`new CustomerBuilder().name("Joe").age(21).build()`

AND

`CustomerBuilder.builder().name("Joe").age(21).build()`

I want the default constructor available because I'm using the builder with the DynamoDbEnhanced client, which expects a public default constructor for the builder to be available. I prefer the static factory way of initializing builders, so that is why I would like the static factory style to also be available.

Is there a combination of properties in the style I can set to accomplish this?
Here is the [reference](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/blob/master/value-annotations/src/org/immutables/value/Value.java) for the possible annotations that can be used in defining an Immutables Style.